# How to optimise apache2 with php5-cgi

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian, web-server, php5

I have a debian squeeze running with apache2 and php5-cgi.
Please see the following stats from my munin:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/545/multipscharts.png/

I am running these per-process stats since yesterday and I'm surprised to see such intensive use by php and also such high memory use by the apache processes.

More data: avg (1day) apache2: 30 busy servers, 9 idle
Avg apache accesses: 340/minute

Now, I was wondering how I could reduce php's cpu usage and/or apache's memory usage.
Note that I'm already server almost all static files by nginx (which is not in these stats).

Also, I'm apparently currently using mpm_prefork_module .
The general settings of my apache2 look as follows:

```
LockFile ${APACHE_LOCK_DIR}/accept.lock
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15

<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>


HostnameLookups Off

Include mods-enabled/*.load
Include mods-enabled/*.conf
Include conf.d/

Include sites-enabled/
GracefulShutDownTimeout 3
AddOutputFilter INCLUDES .shtml
AddType text/html .shtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
AddType application/x-httpd-php-source .phps
```

Any ideas on what settings to look at?

Thanks!

Comment: Make sure that you're using worker or event MPM for apache (less memory footprint than prefork MPM). As for PHP, are running it in fastcgi mode? Paste your apache/php config so we can say something more.

Comment: I can confirm PHP is using fastCGI, as checked with this tip: http://forums.iis.net/post/1895659.aspx

Comment: I also found that mod_php is still loaded. I'll better remove that. Would it reduce memory usage significantly if I disable other unused modules?

Comment: Just for reference... I disabled my unused mod_php and that alone cut apache2 memory use in half. Will change away from prefork_mpm when I find the time